# Nginx + Unicorn Not Serving Rails on Port 80

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I have set up an Ubuntu server on Digital Ocean. I have set up Nginx+Unicorn to serve my Rails app.  However, when I start Unicorn and Nginx I can only reach my rails app on port 8080.  When you hit the address on port 80, it just hits the default Nginx page.

The url of the server is http://192.241.194.250/ and the config files are sitting at https://gist.github.com/davidpatrick/7ee06429abe0c119e835.  Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you see such page (me too) that means `/` is not connected to your app.
Sorry, right now I can't check and test your config. However I have some suggestions:

There **no** `location` clause for `/` so please try something like that:

```
location / {
## Serve static files from defined root folder.
## @unicorn is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below.
try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @unicorn;
}
```

Line `server_name localhost;` that is strange for servers in the Internet. Try to use here FQDN or IP.

Here [good example](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/support/nginx/gitlab) of fully functional and secure config for Nginx and Uncorn